# Evil Eye from one's own wife?

Tags: marriage, mysticism-kabbalah, legal-documents, practical-kabbalah, ayin-hara-evil-eye

Is it possible that one's own wife creates an "evil eye" or something of the sort, knowingly or unknowingly and ends up causing financial and health trouble? Is there any sort of "contract" couples can *sign* between themselves in which one can't harm the other's mazal etc? I ask out of *literary curiosity only*.

Comment: I don't know about the wife having the Eye....the mother in law, on the other hand....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to define what you mean by Evil Eye.

More to the point, the Talmud does mention that a wife's tears can have a tragic effect on the husband's well being.

E.g.: The Gemara in [Kethuboth 62b](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00924.html#HtmpReportNum0121_L2) cites the case of Rav Rechumi was arrived home late for his annual (Erev Yom Kippour) visit.

His wife got so worried that she started crying, and he was killed in an accident as a result.

> כי הא דרב רחומי הוה שכיח קמיה דרבא במחוזא הוה רגיל דהוה אתי לביתיה כל מעלי יומא דכיפורי יומא חד משכתיה שמעתא הוה מסכיא דביתהו השתא אתי השתא אתי לא אתא חלש דעתה אחית דמעתא מעינה הוה יתיב באיגרא אפחית איגרא מתותיה ונח נפשיה

There are other places in the Talmud that cite poverty and other troubles as a result of not treating one's wife with utmost respect.

So, to answer your question: Make sure to always treat your wife with utmost respect, and  then you won't have to worry about her feelings causing you harm.

Comment: It sounds plausible and that's the kind of area I was talking about. I wonder something else though, for example: If I'm an specialist on "A" but while talking (nicely) with my wife she disagrees that "A" should be done in a certain way, mostly due to lack of knowledge on the topic, and gets *offended* (seriously offended, that's how it goes quite often) does it also impact on me? I repeat, we speak nicely, I don't intend on offending her, she just gets offended if her "way" isn't followed etc etc, does her "offended" in this situation also impacts on me? This is almost daily...

Comment: btw, it just happened again: I'm following what is accepted in business standards, regarding meetings, using a CRM (customer relationship management software) and she is helping with scheduling meetings but she just dislikes it and will leave me a note on my desk with an e-mail address and first name of someone, if I complain, even calmly or bring any reasoning to the event she will be offended for a few days etc, regardless of how I bring this up. Does this *offended* also impacts on me? Is shamaim so *blind*???

Comment: Don't know - Rav Rechumi wasn't planning on arriving late... OTOH we know that heavenly justice is precise. Can;t help you here, as I don't do philosophy; I do Halacha, and occasionally quote a source if it rings a bell.

Comment: hahaha good, you aren't a philosopher! I will accept the answer. In fact, I spoke (kindly, lol) to my wife about this and she seemed to know about it in advance (she was born religious, haredish) but we are sorting it out, hopefully it will help other people as well.